# google_osconfig's CPU usage of VM on Google Cloud Platform increases steadily

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cpu

I have been used google cloud platform to offer the services to clients. A few days ago, I found the problem that the CPU usage of VM keeps increasing continuously. For uncovering the reason of this problem, I made the empty(or new) VMs to watch their status, and these new VMs also keeps increasing their CPU usages.

[image]

I used "top" command to know which process takes CPU resources, and the result makes me shocked. "google_osconfig" keeps consuming CPU resources, and it is eating more and more like pigs.

[image]

what is "google_osconfig", and is there anyone who know to solve this problem?

[image]

I restarted google-osconfig-agent to make it release its CPU usage. After using "service google-osconfig-agent restart", the CPU usage decreased.

Comment: I have this same issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/1042509/web-server-cpu-utilization-slowly-increasing-with-lamp-stack

Comment: I may have found some useful information here (perhaps it's a bug?) - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/osconfig/issues/228

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`google_osconfig` It is part of the VM Manager, this definition is in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vm-manager)

> VM Manager is a suite of tools that can be used to manage operating systems for large virtual machine (VM) fleets running Windows and Linux on Compute Engine.

The following services are available as part of the VM Manager suite:

- OS inventory management: `osinventory`
- OS patch management: `tasks`
- OS configuration management: `guestpolicies`

The OS Config agent is installed by default on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), Debian, CentOS, and Windows images that have a build date of v20200114 or later.

You could check the status of this service with the following command:

```
sudo systemctl status google-osconfig-agent
```

If it was a problem with some subprocess that started the CPU consumptions the restart you made will fix it.

But it might a problem with the service, maybe the version you are using has a problem, you could consider [updating the OS Config agent](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/manage-os#update-agent).

To update the agent on CentOS and RHEL operating systems, run the following command:

```sh
sudo yum update google-osconfig-agent
```

To update the agent on Debian and Ubuntu operating systems, run the following commands:

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install google-osconfig-agent
sudo service google-osconfig-agent restart
```

Comment: Had the same problem. 
Updating, like described above, solved it for me, took some minutes for the results to show up.

Comment: Ah... now a week later the 'idle' CPU load has increased to 20% again and is steadily rising, so this was not the answer :(
Completely stopped the service and restarted it... lets see if this helps!

Comment: I've been dealing with this for weeks and every time I restart, the CPU utilization slowly starts climbing again. Very confusing issue. Hope we can figure out how to fix it soon.

Comment: sudo systemctl restart google-osconfig-agent
This restarts the osconfig-agent and brings CPU usage back to normal...
Only to climb steadily over time again...
Could make it a cronjob, but something is amiss.

Comment: I've got multiple VM's running, but only the newer ones have this prob. Since the start of these machines is also got increased API-calls in the Google console...

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/osconfig/issues/261) in some older versions of osconfig (pre-Dec 2020).  To permanently fix, update to a current version:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install google-osconfig-agent
sudo service google-osconfig-agent restart
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1042509/web-server-cpu-utilization-slowly-increasing-with-lamp-stack - the same discussion